# Mixing strings and calls in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm making a spreadsheet of a tabletop game character sheet and I don't want to use multiple cells for the Attack bonus to save space.

Essentially I'm trying to make it end up looking like

```
15/10/5
```

I need to input the `=SUM(I21:O21)` then take that total and -5, then take that total and -5, then do it once more.

I just need to show each step.

Assuming `=SUM(i21:021)` is 30 it should come out as `30/25/20/15`

How would I do this in a cell?

Comment: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers**

Answer (score 1):

the ampersand `&` functions as a simple concatenate:

```
=SUM(E10:E13)&"/"&SUM(E10:E13)-5&"/"&SUM(E10:E13)-10&"/"&SUM(E10:E13)-15
```

Answer (score -1):

**`=JOIN("/"; SUM(I21:O21); SUM(I21:O21)-5; SUM(I21:O21)-10; SUM(I21:O21)-15)`**

**output:** **`30/25/20/15`**